# adding three arrays together to form one array in python

Tags: python

I have an array containing names,3 subjects and the grades for those 3 subjects.
In total the data is:

```
[["Talha","Fazeel","Usayd","Mujtaba","Sufyan","Aukasha","Moiz","Mohid","Wasil"],
   ["Math","English","Science"],
   [10,8,7,4,3,7,8,9,8],[8,8,5,0,9,8,7,5,7],[7,6,4,2,4,3,5,7,9] ]
```

I want a program that print them in columns like this

[image]

the program I made is

```
Name=()
Subject=()
Marks=()
a=[["Talha","Fazeel","Usayd","Mujtaba","Sufyan","Aukasha","Moiz","Mohid","Wasil"],
   ["Math","English","Science"],
   [10,8,7,4,3,7,8,9,8],[8,8,5,0,9,8,7,5,7],[7,6,4,2,4,3,5,7,9] ]
for r in a:
    for c in r:
        print(c,end="")
    print()
```

the output it gives is too much mixed up:

```
TalhaFazeelUsaydMujtabaSufyanAukashaMoizMohidWasil
MathEnglishScience
1087437898
885098757
764243579
```

can anyone help me to sort it out?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: you can copy the link of image and paste it in new tab it will open up...

Comment: Please post the sample output directly into your question rather than using links, images, or any indirect materials.

Comment: The expected output is that image

Comment: I'm new member and new members can't post pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we separate the data from the array `a`:

```
names = a[0]
subjects = a[1]
grades = a[2:]
```

Next we print the first line along with a `print()` call to add a newline in the end:

```
print("Names", end=" ")
for i in range(len(subjects)):
    print(subjects[i], end="\t")
print()
```

Note the use of the `end= "\t"` parameter to add a tab after each subject `\n` after each print call

Next for each `name` we print the name and for each subject we print the name's grade:

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    print(names[i], end="\t")
    for j in range(len(subjects)):
            print(grades[j][i], end = "\t")
    print()
```

After each line we call `print()` to add a newline `\n`

Alternatively, for a little more complicated solution, you can use `%s` to format the string with extra spaces and right justify for a prettier output:

```
a=[["Talha","Fazeel","Usayd","Mujtaba","Sufyan","Aukasha","Moiz","Mohid","Wasil"],
   ["Math","English","Science"],
   [10,8,7,4,3,7,8,9,8],[8,8,5,0,9,8,7,5,7],[7,6,4,2,4,3,5,7,9] ]

names = a[0]
subjects = a[1]
grades = a[2:]

extra_spaces = 2
max_name_length = len(max(names, key=lambda item: len(item)))

first_col_indent = max_name_length + extra_spaces

print(f"%{first_col_indent}s" % "Names", end="")
for i in range(len(subjects)):
    print(f"%{len(subjects[i])+extra_spaces}s" % subjects[i], end="")

print()
for i in range(len(names)):
    print(f"%{first_col_indent}s" % names[i], end="")
    for j in range(len(subjects)):
            print(f"%{len(subjects[j])+extra_spaces}s" % grades[j][i], end = "")
    print()
```

Output:

```
Names      Math  English  Science
    Talha    10        8        7
   Fazeel     8        8        6
    Usayd     7        5        4
  Mujtaba     4        0        2
   Sufyan     3        9        4
  Aukasha     7        8        3
     Moiz     8        7        5
    Mohid     9        5        7
    Wasil     8        7        9
```

For more information on `string formatting` view [this](https://pyformat.info/) document

Answer (score 1):

You can format the cell

```
a=[["Talha","Fazeel","Usayd","Mujtaba","Sufyan","Aukasha","Moiz","Mohid","Wasil"],
   ["Math","English","Science"],
   [10,8,7,4,3,7,8,9,8],[8,8,5,0,9,8,7,5,7],[7,6,4,2,4,3,5,7,9] ]

row_format ="{:>20}"
for sub in ["Name"] + a[1]:
  print(row_format.format(sub), end = "")
print()
for i,student in enumerate(a[0]):
  print(row_format.format(student), end = "")
  for j in range(2, 5):
    print(row_format.format(a[j][i]), end = "")
  print()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
       Name                Math             English             Science
       Talha                  10                   8                   7
      Fazeel                   8                   8                   6
       Usayd                   7                   5                   4
     Mujtaba                   4                   0                   2
      Sufyan                   3                   9                   4
     Aukasha                   7                   8                   3
        Moiz                   8                   7                   5
       Mohid                   9                   5                   7
       Wasil                   8                   7                   9
```

Answer (score 0):

write your lists into a CSV file. It'll store your data, then you can retrieve it easily